# Save a shortcut to a samba share in KDE

Tags: shortcuts, kde, samba, dolphin-file-manager

Using Dolphin in KDE I have opened a particular (password protected) samba share, by typing in the IP address and navigating to the right folder. However I can't find any way to save this location for future use (other than saving the URL to a text file and copy-pasting it into Dolphin).

I would be happy with some kind of bookmark in Dolphin or a desktop shortcut, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Activate **View → Panels → Places** <kbd>F9</kbd>. Drag the icon from anywhere (URL bar, main viewport, folder structure) onto the Places panel.